# Let $A$, $B$ events. Prove $P(A\cap B)\geq P(A)+P(B)-1$

Tags: probability

Let $A$, $B$ events. Prove $P(A\cap B)\geq P(A)+P(B)-1$

**My work:**

We know:

$P(A\cup B)= P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)$,

$P((A\cap B)^c)=1-P(A\cap B)$

Then,

$P(A\cup B)+P(A\cap B)= P(A)+P(B)\implies P(A\cup B)+P(A\cap B)+1\geq P(A)+P(B)\implies P(A\cap B)\geq P(A)+P(B)-1-P(A\cup B)$

Here i'm stuck can someone help me?

Comment: remember that $P(C)\le 1$ for any event C. Thus also for the union of A and B. Then take your stated identity and just substrate by 1 and your are done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost had it on the first line. $P(A \cup B) \le 1$ for any two sets $A$ and $B$, so that 
$$1 \ge P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B).$$
Now rearrange the terms.

Answer (score 1):

We have $$P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)=P(A\cup B)\le 1$$ implying the given inequality

Answer (score 0):

$$P(A)+P(B)=P(A\cup B)+P(A\cap B)\leqslant 1+P(A\cap B)\Rightarrow P(A\cap B)\geqslant P(A)+P(B)-1$$

Answer (score 0):

As you said
$$ P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B)  $$

Which we can re-arrange to give
$$ P(A \cap B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cup B)  $$

Also, we of course know that 
$$ P(A \cup B) \leq 1$$

We multiply both sides by $-1$
$$-P(A \cup B) \geq -1$$

Now we add $P(A) + P(B)$ to each side
$$P(A) + P(B) -P(A \cup B) \geq P(A) + P(B) -1$$

But we showed that the left hand side is $P(A \cap B)$ at the beginning,
which leaves us with

$$ P(A \cap B) \geq P(A) + P(B) -1$$